# How to tell wix installer to run a third party msi in repair mode?

Tags: wix

I have a wix Bootstrapper bundle which runs third party msi as part of the install

How to tell the wix installer to run the third party msi in repair mode?

Comment: why do you need to run the msi in repair mode? doesn't the 3rd party msi know when to fix the installation by itself?

Comment: 3rd party msi is trying to re-install and failing, instead of repairing the existing one.

Comment: can you do a silent installer maybe for the 3rd party? maybe it has more options.. just a guess

Comment: Do you mean that your installer installs some components (which are not already installed), but then tries to install the third party msi, which happens to be installed already, and it fails?